# How to Read from Registry "Name" using VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to Read from Registry the Name.how i can do this using VC++ ?

Ex : I have one folder called ABC in Registry under that i have 3 enteries 
Name , Type, Data.

Now i want to read all Name one by one

```
Name     Type        Data
V:\      REG_SZ      \\124.158.14.74\CIFS
J:\       REG_SZ       \\124.158.14.74\CIFS
```

In my case Name is nothing but drive name's i want to read it one by one.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [RegEnumValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the API you are looking for.

Comment: Correct - just set `lpType` and `lpData` to `NULL` if you need only the name, not the value. The function name is a bit misleading in that respect; it might get the value but it will always get the name.

Answer (score 0):

See the [SHEnumKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773491%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

See the following link, in enumerating registry in windows. Hope this helps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx